# How to combine two pandas dataset based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine two datasets in Python based on multiple conditions using pandas.

The two datasets are different numbers of rows.

The first one contains almost `300k entries,` while the second one contains almost `1000 entries.`

More specifically, The first `dataset: "A"` has the following information:

```
Path | Line | Severity | Vulnerability | Name | Text | Title
```

An instance of the content of "A" is this:

```
src.bla.bla.class.java| 24; medium| Logging found| hr.kravarscan.enchantedfortress_15| description| Enchanted Fortress
```

While the second `dataset: "B"` contains the following information:

```
Class | Path | DTWC | DR | DW | IDFP
```

An instance of the content in "B" is this:

```
y.x.bla.MainActivity | com.lucao.limpazap_11| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

I want to combine these two dataset as follow:

```
If A['Name'] is equal to B['Path'] AND B['Class'] is in A['Class']
Than
   Merge the two lines into another data frame "C"
```

An output example is the following:

Suppose that A contains:

```
src.bla.bla.class.java| 24| medium| Logging found| hr.kravarscan.enchantedfortress_15| description| Enchanted Fortress|
```

and B contains:

```
com.bla.class | hr.kravarscan.enchantedfortress_15| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

the output should be the following:

```
src.bla.bla.class.java| 24| medium| Logging found| hr.kravarscan.enchantedfortress_15| description| Enchanted Fortress| com.bla.class | hr.kravarscan.enchantedfortress_15| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Comment: Why `'com.bla.class' in 'src.bla.bla.class.java'`  is True?

Comment: Also shouldnt the condition is `If A['Name'] is equal to B['Path'] AND B['Class'] is in A['Path']` ? since `A` doesnt have `Class` column

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this the best and the most efficient way but i have test it and it worked. So my answer is pretty straight forward, we will loop over two dataframes and apply the desired conditions.

Suppose the dataset `A` is `df_a` and dataset `B` is `df_b`.

First we have to add a suffix on every columns on `df_a` and `df_b` so both rows can be appended later.

```py
df_a.columns= [i+'_A' for i in df_a.columns]
df_b.columns= [i+'_B' for i in df_b.columns]
```

And then we can apply this for loop

```py
df_c= pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate through df_a
for (idx_A, v_A) in df_a.iterrows():
    
    # Iterate through df_b
    for (idx_B, v_B) in df_b.iterrows():

        # Apply the condition
        if v_A['Name_A']==v_B['Path_B'] and v_B['Class_B'] in v_A['Path_A']:

            # Cast both series to dictionary and then append them to a new dict
            c_dict= {**v_A.to_dict(), **v_B.to_dict()}
            
            # Append the df_c with c_dict
            df_c= df_c.append(c_dict, ignore_index=True)
```